# How to send an array from broadcastReceiver class to MainActivity

Tags: android, arrays, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am working in an Android application that looks for pharmacies that have a specific medicine .all that throw SMS . so the app receive a SMS that contains the name of all pharmacies that have the medicine,saved them in an array named OurString but this array is in broadcast receiver class .i have trid to send a string and it worked but when i tried the array didnt worked.so how do I send array to other class to view the pharmacies's names in a listView.
       This is my BroadcastRecieve class:

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null ;
    String[] OurString = null;
    String str = " ";
    if(bundle != null)
    {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        for(int i=0;i<msgs.length;i++)
        {
            msgs[i]= SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            OurString = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString().split(" ");
            str += " : ";

        }
        for(int i=0;i<OurString.length;i++)
        {
            str += "(";
            str += OurString[i];
            str += ")";

        }
        Toast.makeText(context,str,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("sms", str);
        context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }
}
```

This is where I want to send String, I used pharmacies array to test the listview and I want to replace it with the OurString:

```
public class MedName extends ListActivity {
    String[] pharmacies = {"pharmacy 1","pharmacy 2"};
    Button btnSendSMS,btnShowMap;
    EditText editText;
    IntentFilter intentFilter,intentFilter1;

    private BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            TextView SMSes = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
            SMSes.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("sms"));

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.medicinename);
        btnShowMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowMap);
        btnShowMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent showmap = new Intent("com.example.rana.me_lo.MapsActivity");
                startActivity(showmap);
            }
        });
        btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMeName);
        btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               sendSMS("5666",editText.getText().toString());
          }
        });
        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabHost.setup();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Search");
        spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        spec1.setIndicator(" Search",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.picture));

        TabHost.TabSpec spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Result");
        spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        spec2.setIndicator("Result");
         tabHost.addTab(spec1);
         tabHost.addTab(spec2);
         intentFilter =new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");

         setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pharmacies));
    }

    private void sendSMS(String number, String message) {
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,new Intent(SENT),0);
        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,new Intent(DELIVERED),0);
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"SMS sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        },new IntentFilter(SENT));
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
          @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        },new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(number,null,message,sentPI,deliveredPI);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

       Toast.makeText(this,"You have selected "+pharmacies[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        registerReceiver(intentReceiver,intentFilter);

        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(intentReceiver);

        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Comment: The broadcastreceiver may be running in background and the MainActivity will not be opened at that time..In your scenario will the broadcastreceiver run when the user is on the app...

Comment: i didn't fully understand u . do you mean that the broadcastreceiver will be running only when the app open?

Comment: Ya ...based on how you declare the receiver, it can run only when the app is open or run in background even when app is not open..

Comment: so do i have to implement a thread and then write the broadcast inside it??

Answer (score 0):

You can send and receive array like this:

Send:

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArray(key, new String[]{value1, value2});
Intent i=new Intent(context, Class);
i.putExtras(b);
```

Receive:

```
Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] array=b.getStringArray(key);
```

Comment: It did not work ,it say "Unfortunately ,app has stopped"

Comment: I want to send from onRecieve method in boradcast class to onCreat method in MedName class.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same problem and setting flag as below worked for me
       `Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("list", arraylistOfStrings);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);`
In MainActivity

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
arrayList= bundle.getStringArrayList("list");
}
```

Comment: arraylistofStrings is defined as an ArrayList?? my array is declared like this:String[] OurString = null; ......their is an error because putStringArrayListExtra second parameter accept only java.util.ArrayList and mine is java.lang.string[]