# how to get my app to respond to a SMS from a specific number

Tags: android, sms

i am trying to build an app that response to the SMS of  a specific number, for more demonstration i want a code like this:

```
 if(number == +232344322)
 {
  do something
  } else 
 {
  do nothing
   }
```

So what is the simplest way to do that in android ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `BroadcastReceiver` which will be invoked when an SMS is received.In the `OnReceive` of the `BroadCastReceiver` write the code retrive the number of the sms sender and compare the number and perform task based on that.

```
public class ReceiveSMS extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                Log.v("ranjapp", phoneNumber + " " + message);
                if (phoneNumber.equals("+91xxxxxx"))) {
                    //do something
                }else{
                    //do nothing
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml you need to add:

1. **The receiver with intent-filter within `<application>` tag

   ```
    <receiver
       android:name=".ReceiveSMS"
       android:exported="true"
       android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
           <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```
2. **Permission:**

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>`

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>`

Comment: but i want to do that for a SMS not a phone call

Comment: Np..I will edit my answer. It was not understandable from your question

Comment: i have a teeny question and hope you can answer it for me . i want to send an array from the part where i wrote "do something" to my MainActivity. i already asked the question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953669/how-to-send-an-array-from-broadcastreciver-class-to-mainactivity/31003844?noredirect=1#comment50360133_31003844 but it seems no one understand me.

Comment: Welcom...Sure..will look into that question...If above answer helped you please accept/upvote...